# Is it possible to discover the internal server which is sweeping our network by the gateway Juniper Switch?

Tags: gateway

Is it possible to discover the internal server which is sweeping our network by the gateway Juniper Switch?

Our network topology is like this:

[image]

If the servers under access switch all are different users.  there I have a problem, that is:

if one of the servers DDoS attack all the servers under my network, how can I find it out?

there if like this attack, there must through the gateway switch.

So, how can I capture the source server?

Comment: Do you know the IP address of the scanner?

Comment: I want to get the attack source IP.

Comment: Can you capture packets?  How do you know you're being scanned?

Comment: If you see a sweep you see the packets - the source MAC is the sweeping station. Check the switches' MAC tables to locate the MAC.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to discover the internal server which is sweeping our
>   network by the gateway Juniper Switch

Simple answer is possible. Simply you can find out source address by analyzing packets. But it will not much successful because if attacker knows how to sweep internal network from outside, he never ever use real IP address.

In addition to that, there are many ways to sweep inside network from outside. In my network i detect same situation and my firewall directly shows some ip address which trying to access my internal network. IP address from well reputed telecom company in my country we directly contact them and did inspection. But really what happened was there was virus inside my network It send to Internal Ip address to external source. Then outside firm try to access my network through fake ip address. Fortunately firewall blocked that request it was not allowed to access..